# Unable to locate my device

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

There's a problem with Location... I'm using method to get latitude and longtitude. But my Location variable is null. So my coordinates are 0,0.
Can anybody help me,pls?
Here's code:

```
   public Location getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            checkGPS = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            checkNetwork = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.no_service, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (checkNetwork) {

                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            loc = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        }

                        if (loc != null) {
                            latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                            longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                        }
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {

                    }
                }
            }

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (checkGPS) {
                if (loc == null) {
                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            loc = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (loc != null) {
                                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                                longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SecurityException e) {

                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return loc;
    }
```

loc is null anyway. When I'm compiling app, GPS and wifi are enabled on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're swallowing the SecurityExceptions, I'm guessing your app did not request [permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) and [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), needed for Network and GPS location, respectively.

I generally recommend against silently swallowing exceptions. These particular SecurityExceptions, you should have never needed to add a catch statement for them (that was your clue that something was wrong), b/c you should've called [checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) before attempting to access the resource.